# Error loading python26.dll (14003)

Tags: python, vba, dll

I have a program written in python that i converted into an exe file with pyinstaller. Now i want to run it on a differetn PC by calling it with VBA code.
To directly get the output from the program i used this piece of code i found on the internet:

```
Private Declare Function CreatePipe Lib "kernel32" (phReadPipe As Long, phWritePipe As 

Long, lpPipeAttributes As SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES, ByVal nSize As Long) As Long
Private Declare Function CreateProcess Lib "kernel32" Alias "CreateProcessA" (ByVal lpApplicationName As Long, ByVal lpCommandLine As String, lpProcessAttributes As Any, lpThreadAttributes As Any, ByVal bInheritHandles As Long, ByVal dwCreationFlags As Long, lpEnvironment As Any, ByVal lpCurrentDriectory As String, lpStartupInfo As STARTUPINFO, lpProcessInformation As PROCESS_INFORMATION) As Long
Private Declare Function ReadFile Lib "kernel32" (ByVal hFile As Long, lpBuffer As Any, ByVal nNumberOfBytesToRead As Long, lpNumberOfBytesRead As Long, lpOverlapped As Any) As Long
Private Declare Function CloseHandle Lib "kernel32" (ByVal hObject As Long) As Long
Private Declare Function WaitForSingleObject Lib "kernel32" (ByVal hHandle As Long, ByVal dwMilliseconds As Long) As Long
Private Declare Function GetExitCodeProcess Lib "kernel32" (ByVal hProcess As Long, lpExitCode As Long) As Long
Private Declare Sub GetStartupInfo Lib "kernel32" Alias "GetStartupInfoA" (lpStartupInfo As STARTUPINFO)
Private Declare Function GetFileSize Lib "kernel32" (ByVal hFile As Long, lpFileSizeHigh As Long) As Long

Public Function Redirect(szBinaryPath As String, szCommandLn As String) As String

Dim tSA_CreatePipe              As SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES
Dim tSA_CreateProcessPrc        As SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES
Dim tSA_CreateProcessThrd       As SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES
Dim tSA_CreateProcessPrcInfo    As PROCESS_INFORMATION
Dim tStartupInfo                As STARTUPINFO
Dim hRead                       As Long
Dim hWrite                      As Long
Dim bRead                       As Long
Dim abytBuff()                  As Byte
Dim lngResult                   As Long
Dim szFullCommand               As String
Dim lngExitCode                 As Long
Dim lngSizeOf                   As Long

tSA_CreatePipe.nLength = Len(tSA_CreatePipe)
tSA_CreatePipe.lpSecurityDescriptor = 0&
tSA_CreatePipe.bInheritHandle = True

tSA_CreateProcessPrc.nLength = Len(tSA_CreateProcessPrc)
tSA_CreateProcessThrd.nLength = Len(tSA_CreateProcessThrd)

If (CreatePipe(hRead, hWrite, tSA_CreatePipe, 0&) <> 0&) Then
    tStartupInfo.cb = Len(tStartupInfo)
    GetStartupInfo tStartupInfo

    With tStartupInfo
        .hStdOutput = hWrite
        .hStdError = hWrite
        .dwFlags = STARTF_USESHOWWINDOW Or STARTF_USESTDHANDLES
        .wShowWindow = SW_HIDE
    End With

    szFullCommand = """" & szBinaryPath & """" & " " & szCommandLn

    Debug.Print szFullCommand

    lngResult = CreateProcess(0&, szFullCommand, tSA_CreateProcessPrc, tSA_CreateProcessThrd, True, 0&, 0&, vbNullString, tStartupInfo, tSA_CreateProcessPrcInfo)

    If (lngResult <> 0&) Then
        lngResult = WaitForSingleObject(tSA_CreateProcessPrcInfo.hProcess, WAIT_INFINITE)
        lngSizeOf = GetFileSize(hRead, 0&)
        If (lngSizeOf > 0) Then
            ReDim abytBuff(lngSizeOf - 1)
            If ReadFile(hRead, abytBuff(0), UBound(abytBuff) + 1, bRead, ByVal 0&) Then
                Redirect = StrConv(abytBuff, vbUnicode)
            End If
        End If
        Call GetExitCodeProcess(tSA_CreateProcessPrcInfo.hProcess, lngExitCode)
        CloseHandle tSA_CreateProcessPrcInfo.hThread
        CloseHandle tSA_CreateProcessPrcInfo.hProcess

        'If (lngExitCode <> 0&) Then Err.Raise vbObject + 1235&, "GetExitCodeProcess", "Non-zero Application exit code " & lngExitCode

        CloseHandle hWrite
        CloseHandle hRead
    Else
        Err.Raise vbObject + 1236&, "CreateProcess", "CreateProcess Failed, Code: " & Err.LastDllError
    End If
End If
End Function
```

But whenever i call it with

```
output = Redirect("[path to my program.exe]", arguments)
```

i get the error:

```
Error loading Python DLL: [program path]\python26.dll (error code 14003)
```

The program works good when i call it directly from windows cmd. I also checked the c++ runtime dependencies of the program.exe.manifest and all are there. 
Sorry for the long piece of code but i thought it'd be good to include it.

Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 0):

To run a program made with python, you need the same version of python used to create the program installed in that PC. Like programs created with visual studio that require the redistributable in order to work, the same is for python. You can find python 2.6 from the official site: https://www.python.org/download/releases/2.6/

Comment: yes, indeed. But that is why i converted the python script to an exe file (pyinstaller). So no python installation is required on the user PC. And it works perfectly when i call the program directly in windows cmd.

Comment: once I ran in a similar problem with an executable made with python, from what I remember the only way to fix the error was reinstalling the required version and update the environment variable.

Comment: you can try including the python files in your installer/folder, it should be an alternative way to fix the problem.

Comment: I tried updating the environment variable and i copied all data i thought the program could possibly need into the program folder. But that doesn't help. I think the error must somehow come from VBA trying to open the program (with CreateProcess()) with the wrong c++ runtime dlls...